# Sort list based on string following second delimiter

Tags: sorting, batch-file

Should be easy but after much searching still can't get it. I need to sort a list that looks like this, according to the number following the second slash:

```
 /1628907159142/20141024021655
 /01_B00I7VVZAI_G6/20141028100307 
 /1358737922754/20141013173229
 /1307314535151/20141023185621
 ...
```

These are timestamps. First 8 characters = date. I need the list in date order, earliest first. The time doesn't matter. Ouput would look like this:

```
 /1358737922754/20141013173229
 /1307314535151/20141023185621
 /1628907159142/20141024021655
 ...
```

I'm misunderstanding something here. I've tried many permutations of the following, all of which seem to sort based on 1st token. I've used tokens=2, tokens=2*, tokens=1,2 echoing %%H%%G, and more. Only dif is what part of string goes into the file. The list is always ordered according to number following 1st slash.

```
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=/" %%G IN ('sort ^<Input.txt') DO (
    ECHO %%G >>output.txt
)
```

I found something like below which was to sort lines based on string following a space on each line. I only modified delims and var name for my case. Not sure why 12 dots are added and removed, but figured ok to leave it.

```
setlocal enableextensions
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%a in (Input.txt) do (
    set "_date=............%%b"
    call set %%_date:~-12%%=%%a
    )
    for /f "tokens=1* delims==." %%a in ('set .') do >>output.txt echo %%b %%a
```

Looks like it should work without delayedexpansion, but it doesn't for me. And I can't get the "call set" to work with DelayedExpansion no matter how I use !marks. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sorting before extracting tokens.  The built-in sort does not provide a way to sort based on a delimiter, so you will have to rearrange the input before sorting.  Try something like this:

```
del temp.txt output.txt
FOR /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/" %%G IN (Input.txt) DO (
    ECHO /%%H/%%G >>temp.txt
)
sort <temp.txt >temp2.txt
FOR /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/" %%G IN (temp2.txt) DO (
    ECHO /%%H/%%G >>output.txt
)
del temp.txt temp2.txt
```

Comment: Exactly! So obvious now.

Comment: If you want to avoid the double-processing, you'll need to use something stronger than a batch script. :)

Comment: @Miral - Not true :-) See the beginning of my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26768997/1012053) for an efficient pure batch solution (assuming there are not too many lines)

Comment: @dbenham: I'm not convinced storing values in the environment scales well.  I guess it's fine for a small number of records, but the environment block does have a limited size.

Answer (score 0):

Your non-operating code that tries to use environment variables to sort data is easy to fix:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:: Clear existing _ variables
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set _ 2^>nul') do set "%%A="

:: Load the data into _ variables.
:: The date is in the name, and the full line is in the value.
:: A line number is included in name just in case two rows have the same date.
:: I use FINDSTR /N to establish the line numbers.
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /n . "input.txt"') do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=/" %%C in ("%%B") do set "_%%C_%%A=%%B"
)

:: Sort and write result
:: The SET command automatically sorts variables by name
>output.txt (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('set _') do echo %%A
)
```

But there is a much simpler solution :-)

I have updated my [JSort.bat utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595) to allow you to sort starting at a given token position.

JSort.bat is a hybrid JScript/batch script that provides much more functionality than the standard Windows SORT command. It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is embedded within the script.

JSort.bat is much slower than the native SORT command, and it is limited to a maximum file size of around 10 mb.

Assuming JSort.bat is in your current directory, or better yet, somewhere within your PATH, then your sort operation can be as simple as:

```
jsort input.txt /t 3 /d "/" >output.txt
```

Note that I use /T 3 because there is an empty token at the beginning of each line.

Here is the actual JSort.bat script. I don't promise to keep this code up-to-date on this site. The current version can always be found at [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595).

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::************ Documentation ***********
::JSORT.BAT version 3.2
:::
:::JSORT [File] [/Option [Value]]...
:::
:::  Sort lines of text from stdin and write the result to stdout.
:::  JSORT uses an ascending, case sensitive text sort by default.
:::
:::    File - If the optional File argument is specified, then JSORT reads lines
:::           from the file instead of from stdin. If specified, the File must
:::           be the very first argument.
:::
:::  Options:
:::
:::    /C n - Number of sorted lines to print. Skipped lines are always printed
:::           and do not contribute to the count. Default is -1 (all lines).
:::
:::    /D String - Specifies the string used to delimit tokens. The delimiter
:::           string is always case sensitive. A quote literal " must be escaped
:::           as \q, and a backslash literal \ must be escaped as \\.
:::           The default value is an empty string, meaning treat the entire
:::           line as a single token.
:::
:::    /I   - Ignore case when sorting
:::
:::    /N   - Sort consecutive digits as numbers instead of text. The numbers
:::           may be embedded within alpha text. JSort supports numbers up to
:::           20 digits long.
:::
:::    /O File - Writes the output to File instead of stdout.
:::
:::    /P n - Begin sorting at character position n relative to the beginning
:::           of the selected token. Lines that do not extend that far are
:::           treated as equivalent values, and collate before all other lines.
:::           The default value is 1 (first character).
:::
:::    /R   - Sort the lines in Reverse (descending) order.
:::
:::    /S n - Number of lines to skip - default is 0.
:::           Skipped lines are not sorted (remain in place)
:::
:::    /T n - Specify the token at which to begin sorting. The default value
:::           is 1 (first token).
:::
:::    /V   - Display the version of JSORT.BAT.
:::
:::    /?   - Display this help
:::
:::JSORT.BAT was written by Dave Benham and originally posted at
:::http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595
:::

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:: Get optional input file
set "infile="
set "test=%~1"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if defined test if "!test:~0,1!" neq "/" (
  endlocal
  set ^"infile=^<"%~1""
  shift /1
) else endlocal

:: Define options
set "options= /?: /i: /c:-1 /n: /p:1 /r: /s:0 /v: /d:"" /t:1 /o:"" "

:: Set default option values
for %%O in (%options%) do for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in ("%%O") do set "%%A=%%~B"

:: Get options
:loop
if not "%~1"=="" (
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "test=!options:* %~1:=! "
  if "!test!"=="!options! " (
      >&2 echo Error: Invalid option %~1
      exit /b 1
  ) else if "!test:~0,1!"==" " (
      endlocal
      set "%~1=1"
  ) else (
      endlocal
      set "%~1=%~2"
      shift /1
  )
  shift /1
  goto :loop
)

:: Display help
if defined /? (
  for /f "delims=: tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr "^:::" "%~f0"') do echo(%%A
  exit /b 0
)

:: Display version
if defined /v (
  for /f "delims=: tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr /bc:"::JSORT.BAT version" "%~f0"') do echo %%A
  exit /b 0
)

:: Transform and validate options
set /a "case=0%/i%, num=0%/n%, pos=%/p%-1, tok=%/t%-1, order=1-2*0%/r%, 1/!(0x80000000&pos), 1/!(0x80000000&tok)" 2>nul || (
  >&2 echo Error: Invalid option value.
  exit /b 1
)
set "outfile="
if defined /o set ^"outfile=^>"%/o%""

:: Perform the sort
%infile% %outfile% cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %case% %num% %pos% %order% %/s% %/c% %tok% "%/d%"

exit /b 0
************* JScript portion **********/
var array=new Array(),
    nocase =WScript.Arguments.Item(0),
    numeric=WScript.Arguments.Item(1),
    pos    =WScript.Arguments.Item(2),
    order  =WScript.Arguments.Item(3),
    skip   =WScript.Arguments.Item(4),
    count  =WScript.Arguments.Item(5),
    token  =WScript.Arguments.Item(6),
    delim  =WScript.Arguments.Item(7).replace(/\\(?!q|\\)/g,'').replace(/\\\\/g,'\\s').replace(/\\q/g,'"').replace(/\\s/g,'\\');
while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
  if (skip > 0) {
    WScript.Echo(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine());
    skip-=1
  } else {
    var expanded="", num="", raw=WScript.StdIn.ReadLine(), upper=((nocase==1)?raw.toUpperCase():raw);
    for( var i=pos+FindToken(raw,delim,token); i<raw.length; i++ ) {
      var c=upper.substr(i,1);
      if (numeric==1 && c>="0" && c<="9") {
        num+=c;
      } else {
        if (num != "") {
          num="00000000000000000000" + num;
          expanded+=num.substr(num.length-20);
          num="";
        }
        expanded+=c;
      }
    }
    if (num != "") {
      num="00000000000000000000" + num;
      expanded+=num.substr(num.length-20);
    }
    var obj={expanded:expanded, raw:raw};
    array.push(obj);
  }
}
if (count<0) count=array.length;
if (count>array.length) count=array.length;
array.sort(function(a,b){return order*((a.expanded>b.expanded)-(a.expanded<b.expanded));});
for (var i=0; i<count; i++) WScript.Echo(array[i].raw);

function FindToken(str, str2, n) {
  if (n>0 && str2=="") return str.length;
  var rtn = 0;
  for( var i=n; i>0; i-- ) {
    rtn = str.indexOf(str2,rtn);
    if (rtn<0) return str.length;
    rtn+=str2.length;
  }
  return rtn;
}
```

Comment: EDIT - updated to Jsort 3.1. The prior version had a small bug - couldn't deal with `!` in file path argument. Also added the `/O` option.

Comment: EDIT - updated to JSort 3.2. Version 3.1 had major argument parsing bugs.